# Win the frog race

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I came across this question and cannot come up with a solution. There is a frog race, the frog has a certain number of valid jumpsteps. It can move forward or backward. To win the race, the frog has to move as close to the finishing line as possible, but not overcross it.

Example.
`6, 1 7`

So, the finishing line is `6` units away and the frog can make jumps of `1` and `7` units both backwards and forward. Here, the output should be `6`, since the optimal strategy would be to go `1` unit backward and then `7` steps forward to get to the finishing line.

Comment: [Here's some reading material.](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51595.html) You'll want to take the last equations (`x = x_0 + (b/d)*t`; `y = y_0 - (a/d)*t`) and calculate `min(|x| + |y|)` with respect to `t`.

Comment: The number of hops does not matter?

Comment: @Henry Oh, maybe so. I saw the word "race" and extrapolated...

Answer (score 1):

The positions you can reach are all integral multiples of gcd(valid jumpsteps). If the answer is just the closet reachable position take the multiple just before or at the finishing line.

If you also need the steps, the extended euclidean algoritm can be used to calculate a combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can eat the list in a greedy fashion, considering everytime 3 cases : stepping back, forward, or idling. For optimization, I used a dictionary of already encountered values, and add a final step to each iteration.

```
def knapsack (step_list):
    for s in step_list :
        knap_dict[s] = [s]
        knap_dict[-s] = [-s]
        knap_dict[0] = []
        for key in knap_dict.copy():
            path_length = key-s
            if path_length == max_step:
                return knap_dict[key] + [-s]
            if not knap_dict.has_key (path_length):
                knap_dict[path_length] = knap_dict[key] + [-s]

            path_length = key+s
            if path_length == max_step:
                return knap_dict[key] + [s]
            if not knap_dict.has_key (path_length):
                knap_dict[path_length] = knap_dict[key] + [s]

max_step = 10 
knap_dict = { 0:[] }
print (knapsack ([1,3,1,6]))
```

Since you are potentially doubling the number of keys at every iteration, this is still O(2^n) but I can't think of any better implementation unless this problem can be mathematically simplified.